# rails create page from

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have `Categories` and `Products`. A product has a relation 
`belongs_to :category`

In the categories show page I have a button to add a new product. This button goes to a page where I create the new product, but I need to give the category to the new product.

How can I pass the `id` from the `category` page where I was to the new Product? So, if I am in the category `Electronic` I click 'Add product' and this product automaticaly is associated with `Eletronic` category.

Hope you can understand what I want.
Thanks

Comment: You'll need to show some attempt of trying to find the answer yourself and then ask for help instead of just asking others to find the answer for you.

Comment: the problem is that I already tried to find how to do this but I didn't find what I really wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the `category_id` in your link, e.g. `new_product_path(category_id: @category.id)`.

You will also need to have a field in your product form to save the category's ID, e.g `<%= f.hidden_field :category_id, params[:category_id] %>`

Comment: Thanks, that really helped. I didn't know the hidden_field and I had to change to link_to. I was using a button_to.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would decide whether each product *is contained within* a category, or whether it's simply associated with a category. Hints it is contained would be:

- You expect each product to have exactly one 'parent' category.
- You expect each product will always appear in the context of its parent category.

If and only if you believe this to be the case, I would be tempted to *nest* the product resource within the category.

```
# routes.rb
resources :categories do
  resources :products
end

# products_controller.rb (SIMPLIFIED!)
class ProductController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :get_category

  def new
    @product = @category.products.build
  end

  def create
    @product = @category.products.build(params[:product])

    if @product.save
      redirect_to @product
    else
      render template: "new"
    end
  end

  def get_category
    @category = Category.find(params[:category_id])
  end
end
```

If you do this, rails will ensure your product is associated with the right category. The magic happens in `@category.products.build`, which automatically sets the category_id based on the relationship.

If you'd rather keep categories and products as simple associations, I'd just use a query parameter as per Eric Andres answer, although I'd be tempted to handle it in a slightly different way:

```
# link:
new_product_path(category_id: @category.id) # So far, so similar.

# products_controller.rb
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @product = Product.new
    @product.category_id = params[:category_id].to_i if params[:category_id]
  end
end

# new.erb
<%= f.hidden_field :category_id %>
```

This is mostly just a stylistic difference. Eric's answer will work too - I just prefer to set the value on the model itself rather than have the view worry about parameters etc.

Comment: Thanks for this great explanation. I will not use the nested elements because I am a newbie at rails but it's one more thing I know what rails can do.